# Extension attribute for shipping method in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shopping-cart, extension-attributes, custom-shipping-method

I want to display some custom message from admin in front of my custom shipping method. in extension attribute not set individually in shipping method for custom shipping method of cart and checkout. The same custom message is set in all shipping method from extension attribute.

Please suggest some solution.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got solution and logic.Just Just I have change all extension attribute name after that put condition on current shipping method. Now do your template changes using layout & templates. The extension attribute is very useful and handy for customization in magento2 specially.

Ti's works for me.

Comment: What is the solution for this? any example?

Comment: Can you please add a solution with code snippets on how it worked?